# How to restrict All Contacts (Contact Builder) in Child Business Units

Tags: marketing-cloud, contactbuilder

Within Enterprise 2.0, we have a multi-org integration with Sales Cloud.

The client's enterprise is made up of a variety of regional brands/entities who operate independently as business units e.g. UK, Australia, Spain etc.

Each business unit is connected in one of 3 ways :

  1) A Global Sales Cloud integration - where all contact data is shared

  2) A local Sales Cloud integration - where contact data is specific to a region

  3) Lists / Data Extensions i.e. non-SalesCloud business units.

We have discovered that 'All Contacts' records in Contact Builder is shared across all business units; which is the problem. We want only the contacts owned by a business unit to be visible to that specific business unit under 'All Contacts'

Using business unit filters, we have managed to restrict the 'All Subscriber' records. Each record has an OwnerID, and we used Business Unit Filters to restrict the 'All Subscriber' records which could be visible in the business unit, however we cannot find a method to restrict the same with Contact Builder 'All Contacts' - the same list of contacts remains visible across all business units.

We have checked the Data Designer - every country is configured individually, yet 'All Contacts' appear to be shared across all the business units.

**We need to be able to restrict 'All Contacts' so Australia can only see their contact records** - how on earth is this done in Contact Builder ?

Comment: Hi, not sure why this has been down voted? it's a clear question and no answer easily available on help pages.

Comment: Another user is seeking to edit this question in the first person. Do you have multiple accounts, or are you on the same team? Please just use one account.

Comment: @Clare Restrict the permission for child business unit

Comment: @DavidReed - Clare and I are independent, but she rang me asking. I helped her rewrite the question as it was originally down voted for some reason, so wanted to ensure it was clear

Comment: Simple answer is that I believe it isn't possible in the normal SFMC versions, you would likely need to put this in front of your Sales Rep and they would need to create a custom environment for you.  All Contacts are shared universally because they are literally ALL CONTACTS for your account.